# JSDocs (better docs) 'NODE_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsdoc

I'm trying to configure better-docs with component plugin using their official [tutorial from github](https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/better-docs#component-plugin-beta)

For some reason I'm receiving a weird error.

```
Parsing D:\Projects\train-time\src\stories\StoryContainer.tsx ...
Generating output files...
Generating entry file for "components" plugin
Bundling components
running: NODE_ENV=development parcel build docs\entry.js --out-dir docs\build
'NODE_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\Projects\train-time\node_modules\better-docs\bundler.js:91
    throw error
    ^

Error: Command failed: NODE_ENV=development parcel build docs\entry.js --out-dir docs\build
'NODE_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:630:11)
    at execSync (child_process.js:666:15)
    at bundle (D:\Projects\train-time\node_modules\better-docs\bundler.js:86:5)
    at Object.exports.publish (D:\Projects\train-time\node_modules\better-docs\publish.js:699:3)
    at Object.module.exports.cli.generateDocs (D:\Projects\train-time\node_modules\jsdoc\cli.js:441:39)
    at Object.module.exports.cli.processParseResults (D:\Projects\train-time\node_modules\jsdoc\cli.js:392:24)
    at module.exports.cli.main (D:\Projects\train-time\node_modules\jsdoc\cli.js:235:18)
    at Object.module.exports.cli.runCommand (D:\Projects\train-time\node_modules\jsdoc\cli.js:186:9)
    at D:\Projects\train-time\node_modules\jsdoc\jsdoc.js:93:9
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\train-time\node_modules\jsdoc\jsdoc.js:94:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [
    null,
    <Buffer >,
    <Buffer 27 4e 4f 44 45 5f 45 4e 56 27 20 69 73 20 6e 6f 74 20 72 65 63 6f 67 6e 69 7a 65 64 20 61 73 20 61 6e 20 69 6e 74 65 72 6e 61 6c 20 6f 72 20 65 78 74 ... 49 more bytes>
  ],
  pid: 2928,
  stdout: <Buffer >,
  stderr: <Buffer 27 4e 4f 44 45 5f 45 4e 56 27 20 69 73 20 6e 6f 74 20 72 65 63 6f 67 6e 69 7a 65 64 20 61 73 20 61 6e 20 69 6e 74 65 72 6e 61 6c 20 6f 72 20 65 78 74 ... 49 more bytes>
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! train-time.com@1.0.0 doc: `jsdoc -c jsdoc.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the train-time.com@1.0.0 doc script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Does anyone know what does it mean this error and where is from the NODE_ENV? I'm not using any NODE_ENV in the project

Comment: Research "is not recognized as an internal or external command..." - that's not how you set environment variables on Windows. *"I'm not using any NODE_ENV"* - the command that's being run is `NODE_ENV=development parcel build docs\entry.js --out-dir docs\build `.

Answer (score 1):

The creators of that script assumed you were using a `sh`-like shell like `bash` or `zsh`; the Windows shell is decidedly not compatible with setting environment variables in this way.

I'd recommend installing [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) as a dev dependency. That lets you set environment variables in a cross-platform way that resembles the sh-like pattern of setting variables. For example, in a `package.json` script:

```
"build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development parcel build docs\entry.js --out-dir docs\build"
```